# Laravel 9: Exepción "Unauthorized" al crear/actualizar un nuevo recurso en la db

Tags: laravel

Recien estoy haciendo mis primeras incursiones en laravel y, me encuentro utilizando la versión: Laravel Framework 9.30.1

Estoy creando mi primera aplicación API Rest. Ya he conectado a una base de datos de MariaDB y puedo hacer funcionar la función **Index** de mi Controller.

El problema surge cuando intento usar la implementación de las función **Store** y **update**.

```
    public function store(StoreUsuarioRequest $request)
{
    //
    Usuario::create($request->all());
    //return UsuarioResource::Collection(Usuario::create($request->all()));

}
```

Al probarlos desde Postman, me devuelven la siguiente excepción:
"message": "This action is unauthorized.",
"exception": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException",

¿Alguna idea de lo que debería revisar?

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser porque no tienes definido el token al momento de enviarlo.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: Gracias, Abimael.

Comment: Muchas gracias, Abimael. Ya he solventado el problema. ;)

Answer (score 0):

La solución para mi caso en particular, está en la carpeta requests.
Como yo cree los modelos con el parámetro "--all", se crearon requests files para store y update. Por tanto, en ellos, se define el siguiente método.

```
public function authorize()
{
    return false;
}
```

La solución consiste en poner dicho valor en true.

Saludos.